# angular js - function firing multiple times with ng-checked inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html which has an ng-repeat that generates checkboxes:

```
<span ng-repeat="name in $ctrl.widgetSelectorNames" class="widget-selectors">
        <label class="checkbox" for="{{name}}">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{name}}" ng-model="name" ng-change="$ctrl.toggleVisibility(name)" ng-checked="$ctrl.checkIfHidden(name)"/>
            {{name}}
        </label>
</span>
```

what I'm trying to do is have ng-checked=true, if the relevant item has property of hidden as true. I think my logic is correct, but the ng-checked function runs wayy too many times:

```
  let numTimesCalled = 0;
  $ctrl.checkIfHidden = function (name){
    numTimesCalled++;
    console.log(numTimesCalled);
    $ctrl.widgets.forEach(widget => {
      if (name == widget.name && widget.hidden) {
        return true;
      }
    })
    return false;
  }
```

there are six items in `$ctrl.widgetSelectorNames` yet the function is called 48 times as per the numTimesCalled variable! what's happening? if this isn't the right way to do it, what's a better way?

Comment: can u create a fiddle or Plunker

Comment: that's all I can post unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but for those who want to understand what is going on behind the scene can read.

The `ng-checked` expression needs to be evaluated on every `$digest`.

See here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop